# JdbcTemplate send parameters to multiple statements in one batch

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have the following statement:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id=? AND otherField=?; DELETE FROM myOtherTable WHERE idOther=? AND anotherField=?;";
```

that will be executed as one query (one after the another). So, I have something like the following:

```
JdbcTemplate template;
template.update(query, new Object[]{ 1, "otherValue", 3, "anotherValue" });
```

**which fails with the following error:**

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range:
>   3, number of columns: 2.

I assume that the problem here is that, queries are delimited by a semicolon, and parameters will be applied for each query and it will try to apply the parameters regardless the semicolon. So, I have 4 parameters BUT the first query only receives 2 (the SUM of both queries is 4 though).

Is there a way for me to pass the parameters to the query? ***I can't use named templates***.

Comment: can the downvoter explain why the downvote please?

Comment: Why do the two DELETE statements have to be within the same Java string?

Comment: You can't execute multiple statement at once.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the replacing by myself and then executing the query.